# Programmatically created dynamic table view controller not being called when accessed by the different static table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Although I am basing the static Table View Controller in the storyboards, I am making it access a different dynamic Table View Controller and making different lists spawn based on which option was clicked. There isn't an actual storyboard for the dynmaic Table View Controller but it is programmatically created. The only things that my storyboard for static Table View Controller is connected to are the moving from the main page to this one and a back button to go back.

[image: Storyboards for Reference]

I have two different classes: PollSelectorTableViewController and SubPollsTableViewController where the first is the static storyboard and the second one doesn't have a storyboard but is being created based off of what is being selected in PollSelectorTableViewController. The names all match up properly. My code for 
PollSelectorTableViewController is:

```
import UIKit 

class PollSelectorTableViewController: UITableViewController {
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print (indexPath)
    switch indexPath.row { //depending on which row is selected, place the indicated array into the SubPollsTableViewController so that it can load a new storyboard table viewer with the indicated values
    case 0: //first row
        let setGunControl: [String] = ["Background Checks", "Gun Shows", "Back"]
        let GVC = SubPollsTableViewController(setPolls: setGunControl)
        self.present(GVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case 1: //second row
        let setFavorability: [String] = ["Back"]
        let GVC = SubPollsTableViewController(setPolls: setFavorability)
        self.present(GVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case 2: //third row
        let setImmigrationPolicy: [String] = ["Back"]
        let GVC = SubPollsTableViewController(setPolls: setImmigrationPolicy)
        self.present(GVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case 3: //fourth row
        let setCenterOfDiseaseControl: [String] = ["Back"]
        let GVC = SubPollsTableViewController(setPolls: setCenterOfDiseaseControl)
        self.present(GVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case 4: // fifth row
        let setGlobalWarming: [String] = ["Back"]
        let GVC = SubPollsTableViewController(setPolls: setGlobalWarming)
        self.present(GVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case 5: //sixth row
        let setBack: [String] = ["Back"]
        let GVC = SubPollsTableViewController(setPolls: setBack)
        self.present(GVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    default:
        let setBack: [String] = ["Back"]
        let GVC = SubPollsTableViewController(setPolls: setBack)
        self.present(GVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
}
```

*I am keeping the other case string arrays as one value "back" just so I can focus on the functionality of the first one.

** I added a print statement to determine if indexPath was being called, but it doesn't seem like the buttons are interactive at all anymore.

The code for SubPollsTableViewController is:

```
import UIKit

class SubPollsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var polls:[String]
    init(setPolls:[String]){
        self.polls = setPolls
        super.init(style: .plain)
} //set array to array indicated in PollSelectorTableViewController

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return polls.count //number of rows in table is the number of values in the array.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print(indexPath) //check if indexPath is being assigned
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = polls[indexPath.row] //place each cell name with a specific string in the array
    return cell
}
}
```

The PollSelectorTableViewController is not even registering any clicks and the SubPollsTableViewController is not coming up. Also, none of the print statements are being called. What am I doing wrong here? Is it even code related?

Comment: I just added the picture directly to my question.

Comment: From the information that you've provided the only real way to debug is to put breakpoints – one after the other and see where the control of the program is being lost. I'd suggest starting off from the init method of SubPollsVC.

Comment: I added a viewDidLoad()

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve works with the use of an @IBAction func but I'm trying to determine how to do that without it for when a later case comes up where I don't have the ability to directly connect the code to a storyboard since there is no storyboard at all.

Comment: It seems like the problem is that the function is treating the view controller as if it has two tables. So, it only works when I press the title label (which shouldn't have anything done to it) and on nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You need build the UIStoryBoard before you launch you next view,

First, you set the Identifier:

Open you launch StoryBoard > Right "Utilities" > Identify Inspector (which show "Custom Class")>Identify>Storyboard ID> Give a name in the text field, in this example "next".

In this example, the next Storyboard is "Next.storyboard".

*ViewController:*

```
@IBAction func touch(_ sender: Any) {



   let next = UIStoryboard(name: "Next", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"next")

   (next as! NextViewController).setButtonText("test")

    present(next,animated: true)

}
```

In the present viewController, set you init function manually before call present, above code call setButtonText for initiate the button text.

*NextViewController*

```
import UIKit

    class NextViewController: UIViewController {


        @IBOutlet weak var button: UITextField!

        var buttontext = "button"
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            button.text = buttontext



            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        }

        func setButtonText(_ buttontext:String){
         self.buttontext = buttontext
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }
```

Comment: I'm confused, do I put the ID in the Storyboard that I want to show up after clicking or the one that brings up the that Storyboard?

Comment: I think I was a little unclear with what my PollSelectorTableViewController and SubPollsTableViewController were - I made edits please take a look.

Comment: Because your have Storyboard and this Storyboard with your custom viewController, you need to add the Storyboard ID for the identify which the UIStoryboard use the Custom View Controller.  <br>

Comment: Also you need to call UIStoryboard to build the Storyboard, instantiateViewController(withIdentifier) create the ViewController and init the ViewController by the designated initializer UIViewController  public init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) so you can not create and call your own custom init, instead you call your custom function for initializing after UIStoryboard build the viewController and returned reference for your need.

Comment: I've done all I need for that I believe - I just showed the relevant code here. I clarified the problem a bit more in the comment section of where I asked the question.